# Unable to insert inner tr in a row

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

I'm trying to make a live NBA scores website using HTML, CSS, and JS.
I'm having trouble adding a inner tr under the game scores.

Here's what my table currently looks like:
[image]

Here's my current code JS and HTML:
(My current JS is building up the table and using innerHTML to modify the table under the tableData id)

```js
else{
      data += `<tr>
      <td class = "left">${item.team1} <img src=${item.team1Img}></td>
      <td> ${item.score1} </td>
      <td> ${item.score2} </td>
      <td class="right"><img src=${item.team2Img}>  ${item.team2}</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
      <td colspan="2">${period}QR</td>
      </tr>`;
    }
```

```html
<table>
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th style="width:40%; text-align:right;">Home</th>
   <th style="width:10%;" colspan="2">Scores</th>
   <th style="width:40%; text-align: left">Away</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>

 <tbody id="tableData">
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Here's what I want it to look like (although centered better) and the code I used to build the example:

[image]

```
<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
  <th width= 40% text-align= right;>Home</th>
  <th width= 20%; colspan= "2">Scores</th>
  <th width= 40%; text-align= left;>Away</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody id="tableData">

<tr>
  <td rowspan="2">Celtics<img src=${item.team1Img}></td>
  <td>50</td>
  <td>65</td>
  <td rowspan="2"><img src=${item.team2Img}>Washington Wizards</td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">3QR</td>
  </tr>
  
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Basically, I'd like the "4QR" to be directly under the scores and still on the same row as the team names.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In your javascript template literal, you're missing the `rowspan="2"` on each of the team name <td>. Just an oversight -- you nearly had it.

Added code to an answer, because it got hard to read in a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your javascript template literal, you forgot to put the `rowspan="2"` and it's caused everything to shift over.

```
data += `<tr>
  <td class = "left" rowspan="2">${item.team1} <img src=${item.team1Img}></td>
  <td> ${item.score1} </td>
  <td> ${item.score2} </td>
  <td class="right" rowspan="2"><img src=${item.team2Img}>  ${item.team2}</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
  <td colspan="2">${period}QR</td>
  </tr>`;
```

[image: Table missing 2 cells]

You'll notice your table as constructed is missing 2 cells. Once you "add" those two cells in with the "rowspan", it will all fit back into place.